# dispatch_async usage advantage

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I was checking out this [code](https://github.com/Ramshandilya/FlickrPhotos) when I came across the usage of dispatch_async as :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.photosArray removeAllObjects];
    [[self mutableArrayValueForKeyPath:@"photosArray"] addObjectsFromArray:photos];
});
```

If I am not wrong this line of code is equal to :

```
 [self.photosArray removeAllObjects];
 [[self mutableArrayValueForKeyPath:@"photosArray"] addObjectsFromArray:photos];
```

I am confused as to why the developer chose to use the dispatch_async in this case. Also please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Why do you think they are equal? Don't you think using `dispatch_async` (on the main queue) must do something?

Comment: @rmaddy i agree , but confused as to what the difference would be.

Comment: It is better to ask author of this code about reason it was written. I can see at least one point to use `dispatch_async` here: to synchronize mutable array changes.

Comment: A brief glance at the code you linked to shows that he's doing an asynchronous network request, and the above code is getting called on completion. He is therefore dispatching back to the main queue in order to synchronise the mutations to the arrays.

Comment: Original code should be used in a background thread

Comment: dispatch_async() runs codes in block at next main thread run loop.

Answer (score 0):

These two code snippets are not equal at all. So what does `dispatch_async` do in your case?

1. If it is called from a background thread it runs its block on the main thread and let the calling thread continue doing its business without waiting for the main thread.
2. If it is called from the main thread it runs its block on the main thread but not instantly, a little bit later, on the next run loop iteration, so the calling code will be executed and only then the block will be executed as well